# Magento Installation on Xamp results in a Blank screen

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, magento

I was installing `magento` on my `Windows 7` where `Xamp 3.2.1` is installed

1. Copied `Magento` folder to `htdocs`
2. Create `MySQL` database with a user

and called `localhost:8001/magento` where `8001` is the port for `xamp`

Everything was fine and it prompted to input mysql credentials and i gave mySQL user , password,database and table prefix up on pressing `"continue"` button screen went to a blank screen with no address (`about:blank`) ,

I removed `"local.xml"` on `app/etc` and repeated the steps , no use same screen

Comment: What's in the server logs?

Comment: in xamp where log lies

Comment: If memory serves me correctly, there is an logs directory (c:\xampp\logs). You want error_log

Answer (score 0):

> Q: What's in the server logs?
>
> A: in xamp where log lies

Not where, **what is in**... As contains.

White screen indicates a total collapse of the php interpreter. If you're set to log, it will show the cause in the error log.

Usual cause with Magento is failure to understand this is a resource heavy web application, increase memory_limit to 512M for the newer versions.